# When does $xxyy = xyxy$ not imply $xy = yx$ in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is a follow-up to a graded question on some homework. In attempting to prove that a ring R such that $x^2 = x$ for all $x \in R$ is commutative, I tried using the fact that $xy = x^2y^2 = (xy)^2$ for all $x, y\in R$, so $xxyy = xyxy$. I thought this was enough information to know for sure that $xy=yx$, but apparently it isn't. What is the problem with this conclusion?

Comment: One thought I had is that "whenever $x^{-1},y^{-1}$ exist in $R$, then $xxyy=xyxy\implies xy=yx$".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot simply cancel off $x$ and $y$. To get $xy=yx$ from $xxyy=xyxy$.

Here's a counter-example:

$x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Notice that $xy = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so $xyxy = 0$.
Also, $x^2=0$ so $x^2y^2=0=xyxy$.

But notice that $yx=0 \not= xy$.

How did this happen? Well, cancelation doesn't work when we have zero divisors hanging 
around.

Notice that $yx=0$ (and with both $x$ and $y$ not zero) says that $y$ and $x$ are zero divisors. But in the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices, things that multiply to be zero in one order don't necessarily work that way in the other order as well.

Comment: $x^2\neq x$ in your example, but the OP specified that $x^2 = x$ in this ring.

Comment: I was addressing the error in his logic. There is *no* counterexample in a ring where $x^2=x$ for all $x$ because that implies $R$ is commutative! (The result is true - the OP's proof was wrong.)

Comment: Hm, ok. I don't know if the OP was assuming cancellation but I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is much simpler than it looks but requires a trick. The ring $R$ you are looking at is called a Boolean ring. In any case, for this ring $R$ ANY element squared is itself. So take $x,y \in R$ and consider $$(x+y)^2$$ Try expanding this out and also using the properties of $R$ and see if you can see why that implies $xy=yx$.

EDIT: This did not fully answer your question. It does not hold because your step $x^2y^2=(xy)^2$ is incorrect. This is only true if $R$ is commutative--which is what you are trying to show in the first place. So your question is the same as saying when does $x^2y^2=(xy)^2$ and that is only when $x$ and $y$ commute with each other. Though what you probably want is this to hold for any $x,y \in R$, in which case this implies that it holds generally only when $R$ is commutative.

Comment: It's possible that OP is not reading $x^2y^2=(xy)^2$ as true for all rings, but true given the hypotheses. For if $x=x^2$ and $y=y^2$ then we know $xy=x^2y^2$ and we know $xy=(xy)^2$. The true error is pointed out in Bill's answer: cancellation cannot be assumed.

Comment: I'm a little confused..x = x^2, and y = y^2, so why isn't xy = x^2y^2 right? I understand the cancellation doesn't work from the other answer, but that much at least seems to make sense... (Whoops, addressed in above comment!)

Comment: @Xindaris Under your hypothesis that $x^2=x$ for all $x$, you clearly have $x^2y^2=xy=(xy)^2$. Of course, this is not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

You're instinct is that $ab = ac$ implies $b=c$, which is true with normal multiplication, but can't be done in a general ring $R$, because there doesn't need to be an inverse of $a$ in $R$, so you can't necessarily multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$. But if $R$ is a division ring (every element has an inverse) you can do this.... unfortunately non trivial Boolean rings aren't division rings, so you have to find another way to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

I too think you were seduced by cancellation, and I have an simpler demonstration that cancellation fails dramatically in rings such that $x^2=x$.

The ring could be the field of two elements $\Bbb F_2$, and we would be done. Now suppose it has more than two elements. Then it has an $x$ not $0$ or $1$ such that $x^2=x$. But if you believe nonzero elements can be cancelled, and try to cancel $x$ off of $xx=x$ you get $x=1$, a contradiction. The upshot is that *nothing* cancels properly except $1$!

Rings in which you can do cancellation of any nonzero element are called [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain). Rings such that $x^2=x$ for all $x$ are called [Boolean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). As you can see we have basically proven that the only Boolean domain is the field $\Bbb F_2$.

The right observation to begin with is the one given by mathematics2x2life.